Ramifications of a criminal case by Visale against me
Background of the problem: I went to France in September 2022 for 1-year Master's in a course in English language but I failed the degree due to very serious chronic health issues. I worked on my health while living in France and applied for same course and the universities which were offering English level courses and was selected in two universities and I chose one.
But when I joined the university, the professors told me that they can't give lectures in English. It became very very stressful as there was no help in English and my French level was not upto B2 level since I had applied to English language courses only. I became very depressed to the extent of being suicidal since the courses were not in English and the course incharge didn't even told me earlier despite being clearly asked in April 2023 before applying to their department.
So, I went back to India in December 2023 and from September 2023 to December 2023, I was living in a hostel managed by private company (my lease was till July 2024). While leaving in December, I told them I am moving permanently to India as I have dropped out of the course. I did not took the security money back.  Then in 3rd week of January, I was told that my rent of November and December was rejected by the bank. I had closed the bank account in France around that time and there was about 35 Euros left in it. I did not took this 35 Euros back. Neither I got this money (rent) back in my bank account in November or December. I remember well that I paid the rent and it was not rejected back.
The rent of November was rejected as per their information on 12 December 2023
The rent of December was rejected as per their information on 12 January 2024.
I don't get it why rent was rejected so late in both months (even later than a month) when I paid it on till 7 th of each month and I didn't get the rent back.

Now the Visale says that legal proceedings are continued against you and asks me 1331 Euros! (I got the e-mail yesterday)

Also, I apply for long term study visa for Czech Republic to begin my PhD studies and I needed a Police Clearance Certificate from France and I got it 2 weeks ago and my record is clear! There is no case against me.
Still I want to clear this issue and don't want a criminal case against me in France. I am trying to make things clear now and will pay the final amount.

Question: Can even after getting no cases police clearance certificates of India and France that there are no cases against me I can be refused the long term visa. Will embassy officials have some other ways/information/software to confirm that if cases against an applicant are pending in EU or not?


Is it a criminal case or a civil case? Your subject line says criminal, but you're describing a civil matter.

@littleadv I am writing what visale wrote in the email to me. I have translated the French to English.

The timeline and details seem a bit off. Did you keep or download your bank statements? Did you get a letter regarding your rent (the landlord is supposed to send two, included one by certified mail before involving Visale)? Was there enough money on your account? Did you actually pay the rent or not? Did you get any document regarding the deposit?

An email from Visale is the very first step in the procedure, as DJClayworth explained there is no way this would impact a visa application in France or elsewhere but at this stage it doen't seem they have actually filed anything and you should be able to negotiate a payment schedule with them.

You don't have a criminal charge against you.
In France, as in most other jurisdictions, owing money is not a criminal offence. It's what is called in most places a "civil matter", meaning that it's a dispute between two people, not an offence against the law. The police are not involved, and they wouldn't know anything about it. This is shown by the fact that your police record came back clean. When Visale say "legal proceedings are continued against you" that means they are suing you for the amount owed (although realistically they may not even be doing that). But again, this is a civil matter not a criminal one.
Civil proceedings, especially for a small amount like this, is extremely unlikely to have an impact on a visa application, even if they knew about it. The visa application doesn't ask about it and they won't know about it.
It is probably in your interests to sort out the dispute, and pay the amount if you really owe it. But it won't affect a visa application.

Thank you very much for the answer!

I you think the answer is the best, you can click the tickmark near the voting buttons to accept it.
